# PHPUnit - Throwing, capturing and handling custom exceptions

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I'm trying to test a capturing and handling a custom exception in PHP.

I've extended the base exception type with some extra properties and methods.

One of the classes I'm stubbing can throw an exception, I want to be able to test that I'm correctly capturing and handling that exception (which in this case means building a response object to return from the call).

e.g.

```
try {

    $objectBeingStubbed->doSomething();

} catch (\Exception $ex) {

    if ($ex instanceof CustomExceptionType) {

        $this->_errorResponse->error->message = $exception->getMessage();
        $this->_errorResponse->error->code = $exception->getCode();
        $this->_errorResponse->error->data = $exception->getData();

    } else {

        throw $ex;

    }

}
```

I'm attempted to simulate the exception being thrown with:

```
$objectStub->expects($this->any())
           ->method('doSomething')
           ->will($this->throwException(new CustomExceptionType()));
```

But when the exception arrives in the class I'm testing it's now an instance of "Mock_ErrorResponse_????" which doesn't extend my custom exception. My exception is instead contained in a "$exception" property on the Mock_ErrorResponse.

Is there any way of handling this without being forced to do something horrible like:

```
if ($ex instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_Exception) {
    $ex = $ex->exception;
}

if ($ex instanceof CustomExceptionType) {
...
```

Inside the class I'm testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, instead:

```
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    if ($ex instanceof CustomExceptionType) {
```

you should use try/catch structure:

```
    // (...)
} catch (CustomExceptionType $e) {
    // (...)
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // (...)
}
```

So, answering your question, basically probably you're doing sth wrong. Because when the stubbed method throws an exception, it should throw exactly exception that you've set with `throwException` method.

I don't know how you build your stub (maybe there something is broken, maybe namespaces) but please consider an example below which works fine.

```
class Unit
{
    public function foo()
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        try {
            $this->foo();
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class UnitTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBar()
    {
        $sut = $this->getMock('Unit', array('foo'));
        $sut->expects($this->any())
            ->method('foo')
            ->will($this->throwException(new \InvalidArgumentException()));

        $this->assertTrue($sut->bar());
    }
}
```

Of course you can replace `InvalidArgumentException` with your own implementation exception and this still should work. If you'll still have problems with figure out what is wrong with your code please post more complete example (eg. how you build your stub). Maybe then I can help more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the different try / catch structure. I tried this again this morning and it worked as expected, wasn't able to duplicate the issue I had last night. I'm going to put it down to a silly mistake somewhere from end of day fatigue. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use the @expectedException php-doc annotation built-in in PHPUnit: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions

```
/**
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testBar()
{
    $sut = $this->getMock('Unit', array('foo'));
    $sut->expects($this->any())
        ->method('foo')
        ->will($this->throwException(new \InvalidArgumentException()));
}
```